# Trouble setting up anonymous login with an FTP server in Windows

Tags: windows, ftp

I am attempting to set up a simple FTP server. After creating the FTP server and setting up required parameters for anonymous authentication I still cannot access the directory.

Upon hitting the ftp server through file explorer, I get this dialog:

[image]

I want anonymous authentication, so I check the box and then it asks for an email address.

[image]

After attempting to input an email address with our domain, I receive the following message:

> Either the server does not allow anonymous logins or the email address
> was not accepted. (seen at the top of the screenshots)

I have tried:

- Inputting email address with domain on web server. Double checking
  folder permissions on the server
- set to Everyone can read the
  contents.
- Added new rule for Anonymous access and set to Allow All
  Anonymous Users
- Changed anonymous authentication credentials to
  User:IUSR Pass:blank
- FTP Authorization Rules->All Anonymous
  Users->Read FTP User Isolation->Do not isolate. Start in: FTP root
  directory
- Added the "IUSR" account to the root directory NTFS Security
  Permissions with Read, Read and Execute, and List Folder Contents.

Basically all the steps mentioned in this stack overflow question
(FTP website in IIS with anonymous authentication requires username
and password)

Still having trouble and unable to access the FTP server. Any help is much appreciated.